# Downloading directory (client side) without zipping it

Tags: javascript, webassembly

Is there a way/possible to download a directory (together with sub-directories and files) in the browser? I am trying client side web-worker wasm decompression but downloading it as a zip file kinda defeats the purpose. Downloading a single file (without file path) is easy with href download.

Comment: No, there is none

Comment: No, it's not possible. Http only knows how to work with files, not folders

Comment: @ADyson But this is not purely an http thing. This is a javascript - browser interaction. And am wondering if I missed some kind a new chrome feature. Although hijacking a href can be thought as a http thing...

Comment: Not sure what you mean? If you want to download something from the server then that must be done via HTTP. JavaScript and the browser are one and the same thing, on the client side. The data you want to download is on the server side. Therefore you must use HTTP to access it. And HTTP does not support downloading a folder, it just has no concept of it.

Comment: @ADyson blob:// URI doesn't really have to follow HTTP rules. OP is clearly on a client-side only generation of data (they said they do generate it from wasm.

Comment: @Kaiido hmm, to me "download" means to get something from a remote server, not from the browser you're using on the same machine. But yeah maybe that's what is being discussed. But then again, in WASM / browser there would be no concept of a "directory together with sub-directories and files" either. That can only exist on a filesystem.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, and the browser has access to the FileSystem, so theoretically, the question makes all its sense... I understand that "download" is a bit of a misnaming, but that's how the attribute is called, and if it may help you, think downloaded from memory to disk.

Comment: @Kaiido "the browser has access to the FileSystem"...are you talking about the [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) which gives a sandboxed filesystem within the browser? I guess it could be that yes.

Comment: @ADyson no, I'm not talking about an API, but they can talk to the OS which will give them access to the FileSystem if they wish.

Comment: @Kaiido by what means exactly? AFAIK in a browser environment you do not have access to the local filesystem except by the user choosing a file via an `<input type="file">`. And the only access to the server is via HTTP

Comment: by a lot of internal means. Just check the permissions you have to grant to any web browser in say Android. They definitely can access the OS FileSystem, so theoretically, they could give us access to it, but for obvious security reasons, they don't, or only under very restricted APIs like fetch and that `download` attribute (and more in chrome:// contexts).

Comment: @Kaiido sure, the _browser_ can access the filesystem (because e.g. it needs somewhere to store cookies, history etc). but a web page running in that browser (including associated JS code, WASM code etc) is sandboxed and definitely _cannot_ access the filesystem. What the browser itself can access via its internal code (for the purposes of having a properly functioning web browser) is irrelevant to this issue. The discussion is about what an application or web worker running within the deliberately-sandboxed runtime environment the browser provides is able to access.

Comment: @ADyson, no not only, just like we can trigger the operation of saving one file to the disk, browsers could expose a way of saving a directory, there is no technical restriction (there is even already a Directory interface) and that would not require the script to be able to read anything, nor to get out of its sandbox. The question is valid, that there is no way currently is an answer to that valid question.

Comment: @Kaiido "browsers could" ...but they don't, right now. Anyway I never said the question wasn't valid. I questioned your interpretation of it. And then we got into a bizarre discussion of browser capabilities where it's possible we may have been talking at cross-purposes. We could do with the OP coming back to clarify, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any currently (at least not from Web APIs).
If your concern is that your users will have to decompress the data twice, then one solution would be to use the zip format only as a bundler, with no compression applied on the content.

*But I also have to admit I wonder why you think it's any better to have the unzipping done in the browser if it's not for use inside the browser...*

Comment: Just playing around with web workers and compiling code from C to javascript.